# Tikz arrow with two 90° edges linking two nodes

Tags: tikz-pgf

I would like to draw an arrow pointing from the south of the `t` node to the south of the `e` node. The problem is that I have a slight grade in the edge pointing from the first to the second node.

This seems to come from the fact that the height of the arrow isn't considered within my calculation.

Does anybody know how to consider it? Is there a more elegant way to achieve the desired solution?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
        \node[draw](tID){t};
        \node[draw, right=2.0cm of tID.east](eID){e};
        \draw[->,semithick] (tID.south) -- ($(tID.south) - (0.0,0.5)$) -- ($(eID.south) - (0.0,0.5)$) -- (eID.south);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Like this : `\draw[->,semithick] (tID) |- ++(1,-0.5) -| (eID);`   ?

Comment: @percusse Thank you that was it. What is the meaning of the `++`? If you make a answer out of your comment I will accept it.

Comment: It means it is relative to the last point on the stream. I think we can have it closed as a duplicate if you don't mind.

Comment: @percusse Sure no problem. If you tell me the link to the duplicate I can close it.